# How do I display search results from URL query strings?

Tags: php, html, json, search

I am completely stumped on this one. It might be so simple that I am not seeing it.

I have a website that I am working on where I need to search external websites (only one for now) for files based on a JSON Query String and be able to return search results from the query on the page (basically a mini search engine).

**Example of how I need to connect (email I received):**

http://EXAMPLEDOMAIN.com/api/start_parcels_txn?client=t3vDwH&spatial_intersect=[wkt_geometry]

Where [wkt_geometry] is a url-encoded OGC Well-Known Text point or polygon geometry. The spatial reference system is Spherical Mercator as used by Google and Bing: EPSG 3785 / 3857 / 900913.

The server response is a JSON-encoded object which looks like, in the case of success:
{"status": "ok", "parcel_count": [number of matching parcels], "txn_id":"[transaction id string]"}

or in the case of failure:
{"status":"error","error_message":"[error message string]"}

For example, to perform a point query at the coordinate (-9663031.13, 3962292.03) which falls in the parcel at 1400 University Blvd, Birmingham, AL, form a point string:

POINT(-9663031.13, 3962292.03)

**then urlencode it and pass as the "spatial_intersect" value**:
http://EXAMPLEDOMAIN.com/api/start_parcels_txn?client=t3vDwH&spatial_intersect=POINT(-9663031.13%203962292.03)

**The response from the server is**:
{"status":"ok","parcel_count":1,"txn_id":"sADaOswk3DlfvCLDEFWu7p3Sv"}

To perform a rectangle query which intersects the previous parcel and two others, with the rectangle's lower-left coordinate: (-9663128.4741915, 3962254.4093738) and upper-right coordinate: (-9663033.5250705, 3962386.9798447) form a polygon string:
POLYGON((-9663128.4741915 3962254.4093738,-9663128.4741915 3962386.9798447,-9663033.5250705 3962386.9798447,-9663033.5250705 3962254.4093738,-9663128.4741915 3962254.4093738))

**Then urlencode it and pass as the "spatial_intersect" value**: 
http://EXAMPLEDOMAIN.com/api/start_parcels_txn?client=t3vDwH&spatial_intersect=POLYGON((-9663128.4741915%203962254.4093738,-9663128.4741915%203962386.9798447,-9663033.5250705%203962386.9798447,-9663033.5250705%203962254.4093738,-9663128.4741915%203962254.4093738))
The response from the server is:
{"status":"ok","parcel_count":3,"txn_id":"9skFh7PNdZYJgXyAgDnRXrIWJ"}

I want to be able to have a user input fields with an HTML form (like zip code, address, etc.), then I want to be able to search that on an external website similar to the example above and display the results in the same page. I am having troubles finding online resources to tackle this and I am not much of a coder (more of a systems admin) so I am kind of stuck here. I can understand code but not sure how to implement this.

This can be done with Javascript, HTML, PHP, it doesn't matter I am trying to figure this out easy and maybe an example would help if it exists. If anybody has any insights on this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have so far (accessible at http://s31tech.com/json). I know I still have a ways to go, if you put in **POINT(-9663031.13%203962292.03)** for the spatial-intersect field, you will find a valid response:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    Address:<input type="text" name="address">
    Spatial Intersect: <input type="text" name="intersect">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <br />
    Address entered was: <?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>
    <br />
    Spatial Intersect Coordinates: <?php echo $_POST["intersect"]; ?>
    <br />
    <br />



    <?php
    $url = "http://reportallusa.com/api/start_parcels_txn?client=t3vDwH&";
    $spatial_intersect = "spatial_intersect=";
    //$coordinates = "POINT(-9663031.13%203962292.03)";
    $coordinates = $_POST["intersect"];; 
    $JSON = file_get_contents($url.$spatial_intersect.$coordinates);

    // echo the JSON (you can echo this to JavaScript to use it there)
    echo $JSON;

    // You can decode it to process it in PHP
    $data = json_decode($JSON, true);
    var_dump($data);
    ?>
    <br />
    URL Path: <br />
    <?php echo $JSON; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```